# Importing Custom Gradle Tasks in another gradle when applying Custom Plugins

Tags: gradle

I have a scenario like this.

Currently i have a test artifact for some deployment related tasks. This test artifacts is bundled with testng classes to handle deployment. I have created a gradle task which is calling above testng class in gradle file. Since this is a reusable Component, i am asking all the engineers who want to deploy the product to copy the tasks to their test gradle files.  Now that i want more control on this task, i want to package this as part of Plugin and let the engineers apply the plugin and import the task. Also plan is package the above test artifact with the plugin.

I don't see any working examples on this scenario while searching on google. Can anyone point me to such example.

Comment: sorry, but _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle User Guide has a lengthy section on [Writing Custom Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html). It probably makes the most sense to start there.